# What free expert system can You recommend (with higher functionality then CLIPS)?

Tags: expert-system, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to find best free expert system, with the highest functionality.

I know about CLIPS, but is there another system, for example being able to accept percent of confidence for each rule (fuzzy logic). I need it to know will I be able to do fast a short project using expert system, with highest functionality.

But anyways, it's interesting is there an open source program that aims to gather different AI methods (whitch there are plenty of), and use them together.

So I would be extremely thankeful for any info about more robust CLIPS, or similar programs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "highest functionality", it isn't exactly clear what you are looking for. CLIPS is a very good and very stable forward chaining inference engine. If you are looking for a rule based system with a different feature set, you would need to specify the features that you are looking for.

If you are looking for hybrids that do both rule-based and fuzzy, you might want to look at [FuzzyCLIPS](https://github.com/rorchard/FuzzyCLIPS) or [FuzzyJ](https://github.com/rorchard/FuzzyJ).

Another interesting (commercial) hybrid is [MindBox's ARTEnterprise](http://www.mindbox.com/Products/ARTEnterprise.aspx) which does both rules based and CBR.

Comment: Looks like FuzzyCLIPS disappeared.

Comment: Seems like someone has tried to archive [FuzzyCLIPS](http://awesom.eu/~cygal/archives/2010/04/22/fuzzyclips_downloads/index.html)

Comment: I have used [jFuzzyLogic](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/). It supports fuzzy,rules and also allows to optimize parameters.